# Cannot trouble dropping unique constraint

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, constraints, unique-constraint

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE FlightInstance (
FLNO INT,
FDate VARCHAR(10),

PRIMARY KEY (FLNO, FDate)
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

I added the following constraint:

```
    ALTER TABLE FlightInstance ADD CONSTRAINT FDATE_UNIQUE UNIQUE (FDate);
```

I added this constraint in order to be able to use `FDate` as a reference key and do this (Otherwise I would get an error):

```
    ALTER TABLE FlightLegInstance ADD FOREIGN KEY (FDate) REFERENCES
    FlightInstance(FDate);
```

So I was populating my tables and ran across a problem with these 2 entries into the `FlightInstance` table:

```
    INSERT INTO FlightInstance (FLNO, FDate) VALUES (1000 ,"10/5/2015");
    ...
    INSERT INTO FlightInstance (FLNO, FDate) VALUES (1010 ,"10/5/2015");
```

So I assumed I needed to drop the unique constraint `FDATE_UNIQUE` since I have 2 of the same values in `FDate`, but I get this error when issuing this command:

```
    Error on rename of './foo/#sql-699d_5b353' to './foo/FlightInstance' (errno:

    150)
```

So I did some research and some said I should delete my foreign key constraint since I'm using INNODB so I successfully did with the following command:

```
    alter table FlightInstance drop foreign key  FlightInstance_ibfk_1;
```

But I still get the same error as above. The command I'm using is:

```
    alter table FlightInstance drop index FDATE_UNIQUE;
```

Instead of `index` in the command I've also used `UNIQUE KEY` to no avail.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably still another foreign key referencing the index, this is why the drop index cannot succeed.

In order to find out which foreign key causes the error, run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` right after trying to drop the index and then check out the `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR` section.

Comment: Yes, there's another foreign key that references this. I know what table it is. But what do I do with that information? I still want it to be a reference key for both `FlightLegInstance` (as used in this post) and the other table. Is there a way to use `FDate` as a reference without imposing the unique constraint? Sorry, I'm just stuck on how to go about solving this.

Comment: Yes, you can do that, since an index does not have to be unique. So, delete all foreign keys first, then delete the unique index, then add a non-unuque index on fdate, then add the foreign keys back.

Answer (score 0):

@Kenshin, you defined foreign key on FlightLegInstance and not FlightInstance. Hence you have to drop the foreign key from FlightLegInstance. I tried and it worked as shown below:

```
mysql> alter table FlightLegInstance drop foreign key  flightlegInstance_ibfk_1
```

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>  alter table FlightInstance drop index FDATE_UNIQUE;

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.23 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO FlightInstance (FLNO, FDate) VALUES (1010 ,"10/5/2015");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)